# Running Spring application outside of an IDE (preferably OS shell)

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

https://www.pegaxchange.com/2018/01/24/java-web-project-with-spring-framework/   has instructions for creating a Java Web Project with Spring, without Maven.  I am able to get it working in an Eclipse environment.  It works as expected by doing “Run As” --> “Run on Server”.

When I kill Eclipse I get the Status 404 error (“*The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.*”).  I have verified that the Tomcat Server is running from the XAMPP Control Panel.

How do I launch the application from an OS shell (Windows & Linux) so that I don't see the 404 error?

Answer (score 0):

Its been a long time I haven't used java web projects without maven but if my memory serves me right, you should first export your project as .war file. Then deploy it to tomcat.

1. In eclipse right click your project select export and then select WAR file.
2. Copy your WAR file into `webapps` directory which is located in tomcat installation directory.
3. Rename the WAR file as you like if you want to serve you web app with a specific context name something like `http://localhost:8080/myapp`. If you do want to serve as root without a context name just rename it as "ROOT".
4. Run tomcat by command line `<your-tomcat-installation-dir>\bin\startup.sh` or it will be a .bat file for windows so you should end your command with `.bat`.
5. Or if you can start and stop by XAMPP panel this should do the same as well.

Also you can see [this article](https://www.baeldung.com/tomcat-deploy-war) for details on how to deploy a war file to tomcat.

I hope this helps. Cheers!